# ng view not rendering jade templates

Tags: angularjs, express, pug

I want to set up angular with ng-route using JADE.  I cannot connect to my templates(where I am storing my html files).  Below are the steps. I apologize that it is  long, but I wanted to show everything involved Any advice to setting up angular with express is much appreciated!!!!

```
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

In my layout.jade I identified all of the script tags that I will be using.

```
    script(src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.js")
    script(src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-resource.js")
    script(src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-route.js")
    script(src="/client.js")
```

In my index.jade

```
extends layout

block content
    div(ng-view)
```

I created a **templates**  folder inside of my views and am housing my home page there.

Here is are the contents of my  **public folder** .

```
var beerApp = angular.module('beerApp',['ngResource','ngRoute']);

beerApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl:'/templates/home',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })

});



beerApp.controller('homeController',function(){
    console.log('controller set up')

});
```

My first assumption was that inside of my controllers I must need to set up request for the **tempates** so I did.

```
var indexController = {
index: function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
},
getTemplate: function(req,res){
    res.render('templates/', + req.params.templateid);
}
```

};

```
module.exports = indexController;
```

Rendering templates did nothing to fix my error.  Home.html is not being found in my chrome dev tools.

Comment: Have you miss `ng-app` in layout template?

Comment: No I have that as well

Answer (score 0):

**routes/templates.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET template by name */
router.get('/:templateid', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('templates/' + req.params.templateid);
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js** - so you have access to templates by url, eg. `templates/home` - check if broweser can render this template

```
app.use('/templates', require('./routes/templates'));
```

**templates/home.jade** - use pipe for marking text as raw content

```
p
  | {{ hello }}
```

**client.js**

```
beerApp.controller('homeController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.hello  = 'hello world';
});
```